# Show bash script output on html page

Tags: javascript, html, bash

I have a bash script to get some devices status/packet loss that looks something like this (changed the names/ip addresses):

```
#!/bin/bash

TSTAMP=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

device1=`ping -c 1 100.1.0.2 | grep packet | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 " " $8 }'`
device2=`ping -c 1 100.1.0.3 | grep packet | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 " " $8 }'`
device3=`ping -c 1 100.1.0.4 | grep packet | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 " " $8 }'`
device4=`ping -c 1 100.1.0.5 | grep packet | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 " " $8 }'`
device5=`ping -c 1 10.1.0.250 | grep packet | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 " " $8 }'`
device6=`ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | grep packet | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 " " $8 }'`

echo "Device 1: ${device1}"

echo "Device 2: ${device2}"

echo "Device 3: ${device3}"

echo "Device 4: ${device4}"

echo "INTERNET WITH ${device5}"

echo "Device 6 Proxy : ${device6}"

echo "Last update ${TSTAMP}"
```

I need to show that output in my HTML page.

Some people told me to use JavaScript to extract the status/packet loss, put them together in a JSON object and throw it to my page from there. But i don't know how to do that or if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: simple enough with jquery. `$('#somediv').load('/cgi-bin/yourscript.sh')`, which would simply suck up the script's output and spit it out into the specified area of your page. 'course, you'd have to write the bash script as a proper CGI script, which means outputting a basic http response header at least.

Answer (score 0):

You only use cgi-bin for simple websites, so use a simple solution:
Show the output of your script as preformatted test:

```
echo "<pre>"
echo "Your ping results"
echo "</pre>"
```

When this works, you may want to use some light html code:

```
echo "<html>
<head>StackOverflow helps</head>
<body>
<br/>
My ping results are ...
<br/>
<table><tr><td>"
echo "your ping results"
echo "
</tr></td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
"
```

When you have different scripts that need a similar html layout, you can make a html file and put a placeholder where the results come. All you need to do is to stream the html file in your script and replace the placeholder with the results to display.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with PHP:

```
<?php
$TSTAMP = date('Y-m-d h:i');

$device1 = shell_exec("ping -c 1 100.1.0.2 | grep packet | awk '{ print $6 \" \" $7 \" \" $8 }'");
$device2 = shell_exec("ping -c 1 100.1.0.3 | grep packet | awk '{ print $6 \" \" $7 \" \" $8 }'");
$device3 = shell_exec("ping -c 1 100.1.0.4 | grep packet | awk '{ print $6 \" \" $7 \" \" $8 }'");
$device4 = shell_exec("ping -c 1 100.1.0.5 | grep packet | awk '{ print $6 \" \" $7 \" \" $8 }'");
$device5 = shell_exec("ping -c 1 10.1.0.250 | grep packet | awk '{ print $6 \" \" $7 \" \" $8 }'");
$device6 = shell_exec("ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | grep packet | awk '{ print $6 \" \" $7 \" \" $8 }'");

echo "Device 1: ${device1}<br />";
echo "Device 2: ${device2}<br />";
echo "Device 3: ${device3}<br />";
echo "Device 4: ${device4}<br />";
echo "INTERNET WITH: ${device5}<br />";
echo "Device 6 Proxy : : ${device6}<br />";
echo "Last Update ${TSTAMP}";
?>
```

Now the issue with this, is that PHP is a server side language. It means that when you run the website, you will always get results from the point of view of the server. This is not the case with Client side languages, like Javascript (as this post is tagged).

The other issue is to make sure your web server has PHP installed so that this file can be executed.

If you were looking for a file you could open up on your computer, this isn't it, unless you installed PHP locally.